# What's the easiest way to assign a string returned from the server to a javascript string?

Tags: javascript, string

The following does not work:

```
var js_str= '<?php echo $str_from_server; ?>';
```

The problem is that, $str_from_server can contain **any** characters. If it contains single quotes or line breaks or others, the above code will break. And I do not have access to the server-side code. What's the easiest way to "escape" the contents of $str_from_server into a javascript string, and then it can be restored later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are echoing that variable to your JavaScript code directly, you could use the [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function:

```
var js_str = <?php echo json_encode($str_from_server); ?>;
```

It will safely escape quotes for you, e.g.:

```
<?
  $str ='"\'"\'"\'"';
  echo  json_encode($str); // "\"'\"'\"'\""
```

Comment: If you're in a `<script>` element (which is likely for PHP), add the $options argument `JSON_HEX_TAG` to avoid `</` in the string ending the block.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
var js_str= '<?= addslashes($str_from_server); ?>';
```

or:

```
var js_str= '<?= str_replace("'", "\'", $str_from_server); ?>';
```